# How to manage InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview

I have a method that paints all the cells of a `datagridview` with a condition.

I parse all the table values before painting them because I have to know whats the cell value to decide what is going to be the color.

The code is this one:

```
private void rowPainting()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
        {

            try
            {
                double value= Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[j, i].Value);

                if ((value> 0) && (value<= 10))
                {
                    dataGridView1[j, i].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 254, 243);

                } else if {

                    dataGridView1[j, i].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 254, 243);        

                }
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException)
            {                         
                Console.WriteLine("value null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that some cell are null and when i convert the cell object into a double, it generates an

> InvalidCastException

I want to color those rows that generates me an exception and continue the program.
How can I "do nothing" with this exception and continue the program normally?

Comment: check `dataGridView1[j, i].Value` for null before you try to convert it and convert only if value is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
double value = 0;

if ( !double.TryParse( dataGridView1[j, i].Value, out value ) )
{
    // Do something in here...

}

// Then modify your if statement like so:
if ( ( value > 0 ) && ( value <= 10 ) )
{

}
else if ( value == 0 )
{

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if ( dataGridView1[j, i].Value == null) continue;
>   double value=
>   Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[j, i].Value);

Comment: He wants to: "I want to color those rows that generates me an exception"